# Class with heap memory allocation, 2 instances share a pointer (pointer being freed was not allocated)

Tags: c++, malloc, new-operator, dynamic-arrays

I need some wrapper around C++ dynamic arrays, so a class with following properties:

```
class Dyn_array {
    std::string name;
    int length;
    int* head;
}
```

Also I have to overload `*`/`*=` operators, but I can't return the result because I get already mentioned error, probably the problem is with constructors/destructors: either I call some destructor twice, or, more probably, 2 instances share a pointer. Yes, indenting is wrong, I don't know why emacs behaves like this.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Dyn_array {
    std::string name;
    int length;
    int* head;
    public:
        Dyn_array()
            : name("Unknown"), length(0), head(nullptr)
        {
            std::cout << "Default constructor of " << name << " is being used.\n";
        }
        Dyn_array(std::string n_name, int n_length)
            : name(n_name), length(n_length), head(new int[n_length])
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < n_length; i++) {
                head[i] = 0;
            }
            std::cout << "Constructor with parameters of " << name << " is being used.\n";
        }
        void add(int n_element) {
            if (head) {
                head[length] = n_element;
            }
            else {
                head = new int(n_element);
            }
            length++;
        }
        Dyn_array(std::string n_name, int* array, int size)
            : name(n_name), length(0), head(nullptr)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                add(array[i]);
            }
            std::cout << "Constructor with array of " << name << " is being used.\n";
        }
        ~Dyn_array() {
            if (head) {
                delete[] head;
                head = nullptr;
                length = 0;
            }
            std::cout << "Destructor of " << name << " with address " << head << " is being used.\n";
        }
        int& operator[](int i) {
            return head[i];
        }
        int operator[](int i) const {
            return head[i];
        }
        Dyn_array(const Dyn_array& rhs) {
            (*this).~Dyn_array();
            std::cout << "Copy constructor is being used.\n";
            for (int i = 0; i < rhs.length; i++) {
                add(rhs[i]);
            }
        }
        Dyn_array& operator*= (const Dyn_array& rhs) { // HERE------------
            Dyn_array temp; // Creating an instance to store result
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                bool check = false;
                for (int j = 0; i < rhs.length; i++) {
                    if (head[i] == rhs.head[j]) {
                        check = true;
                    }
                }
                if (check) {
                    temp.add(head[i]);
                }
            }
            temp.add(53); // For debugging
            (*this) = Dyn_array(temp); // Copy constructor calling
            return (*this);
        }
        void print() {
            if (head) {
                for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                    std::cout << head[i] << " ";
                }
                std::cout << '\n';
            }
            else {
                std::cout << "Array is empty.\n";
            }
        }
};

int main() {
    int arr1[3] = {1, 2, 3};
    int arr2[4] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
    Dyn_array a("first", arr1, 3);
    Dyn_array b("second", arr2, 4);
    a.print();
    b.print();
    b *= a;
    a.print();
    b.print();
}
```

Comment: `(*this).~Dyn_array();` why are you doing this? You destroy `this` and then continue to use it. That doesn't look right

Comment: Copy constructor, as the name suggests, should create a copy, not destroy the original object.

Comment: @idclev463035818 I destroy it because I will store there a copy I'll make. I continue to use it because `add` should work even with `head = nullptr` — instance after destructing are basically the same as instances created with default constructor.

Comment: `add` doesn't increase the size of the array and when `head` is null allocates a single element rather than an array

Comment: @OleksiiHaponiuk `add()` may work, but your `operator[]` surely will not. And since the object is destroyed, any use of that object is Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: @AlanBirtles it increases `length` in last line, but you're right, it doesn't create an array. But is it any different? I mean, this is the way constructor with static array (last one) works, and it works right.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen what's wrong with `operator[]`?

Comment: Your constructor may not immediately crash but it is certainly not `working right` and causing memory corruption that will cause a crash at some point in the future

Comment: Oh, right, you are destroying `this`, not `rhs`. This is still UB, but it may appear to work.

Comment: There is nothing to destroy, copy constructor creates object, you can't write into destroyed object. Also, `head = new int(n_element);` is a mistake, you create one element with value `n_element`.  `operator[]` would yield ub if attempting accessing anything but 0.   `delete[]` also will be UB.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie why `operator []` and `delete[]` are wrong?